# How do I set up a many-to-many relationship in iOS? (Core Data)

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data, many-to-many

I'm relatively new to core data, and have used one-to-many relationships frequently. Yet I'm currently in a situation where having a many-to-many relationship makes sense. I have users and groups, users can have many groups and groups will have many users. Yet it occurred to me I have no clue how to set this up.

To add a user to a group I would normally do something like...

```
Group *group = [NSEntityDescription
                        insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Group"
                        inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
group.user = myUser;
```

But now I have `group.users` (plural) and I can't figure out what I'm supposed to populate that with. Should it be an `NSArray` with my user objects? If so, does that mean every time I want to add a new user I first have to fetch all the current users, stick it in an array, update that array with the new user, then assign it `group.users`?

I can't imagine I'd have to do something that ridiculous; would someone give me a basic explanation as to how I build a many-to-many relationship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of a to-many relationship is a `NSSet`, not an `NSArray`. But you can use
the generated Core Data accessor methods to add an element to a to-many relationship.
For example:

```
User *user = ...;
Group *group = ...;

// Add user to group:
[group addUsersObject:user];  // (1)
// Or, alternatively, add group to user:
[user addGroupsObject:group]; // (2)
```

(You can do either (1) or (2). If the relationships are defined as *inverse* relationships
of each other, one automatically implies the other.)

Comment: Yeah I figured it out. Was finally going to get around to updating this, but guess I don't need to.

Answer (score 0):

you can use NSDictionary or NSMutableDictionary that holds your objects in n<->n relation.

Answer (score 0):

The Core Data Programming Guide on Apple's developer site is very thorough.  There is a section in the middle of the page at the link below that covers how to create a many-to-many relationship.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdRelationships.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001857-SW10

Comment: Links can be helpful as supplemental information, but [link-only answers are strongly discouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/228805). Answers should actually *answer* the question, not just give general tips and pointers about how to investigate or where to find helpful information (such things can be posted as [comments](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Please include a summary of the linked information that's relevant to the question, and explain how it resolves the issue.

Comment: Ok thanks.  I have been using the site for a while, but just started commenting.

Comment: I've already read through that. Nowhere on the page does it show how to actually add and remove objects in a many-to-many relationship.